# Can't load package in brand new Go project

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm trying modules in Go. I'm outside the `GOPATH` and using version `1.12.6`:

```sh
GOBIN="/home/x80486/Workshop/go/bin/"
GOPATH="/home/x80486/Workshop/go/"
GOROOT="/home/x80486/.asdf/installs/golang/1.12.6/go/"
```

I created a new project and initialized it as a module inside: `/home/x80486/Workshop/Development/gauge-basics`. I then created a file `example_spec.go` with this content:

```golang
package stepImpl

import (
  "github.com/getgauge-contrib/gauge-go/gauge"
)

var _ = gauge.Step("Run me before any other", func() {})
```

...and I ran `go test`:

```sh
[x80486@uplink gauge-basics]$ go test
go: finding github.com/getgauge-contrib/gauge-go/gauge latest
go: finding github.com/getgauge/common latest
go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf/proto latest
go: finding github.com/dmotylev/goproperties latest
?       github.com/x80486/gauge-basics  [no test files]
```

Everything is somehow OK, but as soon as I move this file into a folder named `stepImpl`, nothing works:

```sh
[x80486@uplink gauge-basics]$ go build
can't load package: package github.com/x80486/gauge-basics: unknown import path "github.com/x80486/gauge-basics": cannot find module providing package github.com/x80486/gauge-basics
```

I can't understand why moving a file to a folder with the package name would break the project.

---

This is the generated `go.mod` file:

```
module github.com/x80486/gauge-basics

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/dmotylev/goproperties v0.0.0-20140630191356-7cbffbaada47 // indirect
    github.com/getgauge-contrib/gauge-go v0.1.3 // indirect
    github.com/getgauge/common v0.0.0-20190514095629-619e107433ce // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2 // indirect
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no .go files under github.com/x80486/gauge-basics, because you moved them under a different directory. You can run go build under the directory containing the source files or add another .go in the gauge-basics directory importing them.